# Error copying Files when setting up Xampp

Tags: unity, lamp, xampp

I was attempting to install the xampp(5.6) after uninstalling lamp from my ubuntu 17.04 but it shows me this error when setting up xampp .
I'm new to ubuntu and I can't  find out  the problem .

[This is the error shown when setting up Xampp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5Iww.jpg)

Comment: Did you run the installer with `sudo` as it installs to `/opt` folder that only sudo members and root  can write to?

Comment: yes I used these steps chmod 755 xampp-linux-*-installer.run    
sudo ./xampp-linux-*-installer.run  and all good the problem is only when setting up xampp . Did you see the error in the picture ? thank you for replying .

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same  issue, later I found out that because of a ***memory issue***,
If you **increase your volume size**, it will solve the problem